# Dealing with time format beyond 24 hours and do some maths

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

In my `data.table`, I have a character column representing time, and I have to do some tests, some maths on this column.

I choosed to use `lubridate::hms()` to convert character because of time greather than 24 hours, i.e. `"26:35:20"`.

Let see reprex and firsts steps :

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

foo <- data.table(id = seq(1:5),
                  mytime = c("03:45:12", "17:56:00", "26:32:63", "09:00:00", "35:05:55"))

foo[, hmstime := hms(mytime)]
```

This :

```
testingtime <- hms("12:00:00")
addingtime <- hms("24:00:00")

testingtime + hours(24) 
testingtime + addingtime
```

And this :

```
foo[, addtime := hmstime + addingtime]

foo[hmstime < testingtime, "test1" := "ok"]
```

run fine.

But this doesn't run :

```
foo[hmstime < testingtime, "test2" := hmstime + addingtime]
```

And I can't seem to find out why...
Maybe I was on the wrong track from the start ?
But I can't find another way to achieve this.

Many thanks !

Comment: i think the problem, you want to add the times only when the condition is true! NA is creating a problem. ````bind_rows(foo %>% filter(hmstime < testingtime) %>% mutate(test2 = hmstime + addingtime),foo %>% filter(hmstime >= testingtime))````

Comment: I am not totaly sure of what you said. This ```data.table``` syntax works great on classical case. And this is running : ```foo[hmstime < testingtime, "test3" := hmstime + 5000]```.

Answer (score 4):

Before that call, `test2` does not exist. The conditional new assignment typically sets `NA` for all other rows, but the data returned by that call is not so easily worked into that flow:

```r
### non-assignment, just evaluating
dput(foo[hmstime < testingtime, hmstime + addingtime])
# new("Period", .Data = c(12, 0, 12, 0, 12), year = c(0, 0, 0, 
# 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(27, 
# 41, 50, 33, 59), minute = c(45, 56, 32, 0, 5))
```

My guess (without diving into `data.table`-internals) is that it doesn't know how to work a `new(...)` object interspersed with `NA`s into the new column. Admittedly, it's not something I do frequently, either.

Workaround: assign *all* the new value, then `NA`-out the remainder.

```r
foo[, "test2" := hmstime + addingtime][hmstime >= testingtime, test2 := NA]
foo
#       id   mytime     hmstime     addtime  test1       test2
#    <int>   <char>    <Period>    <Period> <char>    <Period>
# 1:     1 03:45:12  3H 45M 12S 27H 45M 12S     ok 27H 45M 12S
# 2:     2 17:56:00  17H 56M 0S  41H 56M 0S   <NA>        <NA>
# 3:     3 26:32:63 26H 32M 63S 50H 32M 63S   <NA>        <NA>
# 4:     4 09:00:00    9H 0M 0S   33H 0M 0S     ok   33H 0M 0S
# 5:     5 35:05:55  35H 5M 55S  59H 5M 55S   <NA>        <NA>
```

I want to suggest prefilling with another `Period` throw-away value (such as `NA`), but that fails too:

```r
foo[, test2 := hmstime[NA]][hmstime < testingtime, test2 := hmstime + addingtime]
# Error in `[.data.table`(foo[, `:=`(test2, hmstime[NA])], hmstime < testingtime,  : 
#   Supplied 5 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'test2'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

suggesting that the issue really is in subsetting the `new(...)` to fit into the column. Note that the first suggestion (that works) in fact *does* work because it is assigning a simple `NA` value into an existing column, it is not trying to fit a `new(...)` into a column.

This might be a bug or feature-request for `data.table`, over to you.

---

Another workaround that is much closer to the canonical `data.table` way of doing things, thanks @Frank:

```r
foo[hmstime < testingtime, test3 := hmstime[.I] + addingtime]
```

Comment: Thank you for all this detail. If only I didn't have these hours beyond 24 hours...

Comment: Another workaround: `foo[hmstime < testingtime, test3 := hmstime[.I] + addingtime]`

Comment: Discus23, does this resolve your question? (If so, please accept it. Thanks!)